# How to hide div with class name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I am trying to hide the visibility of this div class however javascript code that I have written didn't work.What should I do in this situation?

```html
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-display webform-component--1-contact-1-bg20-custom-4">
  <label>Question? </label>
 Nein
</div>



<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("form-item webform-component webform-component-display webform-component--1-contact-1-bg20-custom-4").style.visibility = '"hidden";
</script>
```

Comment: It's not a class name having spaces. It's 4 different class names.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things

1. It's not a single classname having spaces, it's four different classes in a single div
2. You have put up an extra single quote before double cotes.
3. getElementsByCLassName returns an array so you need to specify index

Ideally, it should be

```html
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-display webform-component--1-contact-1-bg20-custom-4">
<label>Question? </label>
Nein
</div>


<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("form-item")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
```

Or if we write it your way

```html
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-display webform-component--1-contact-1-bg20-custom-4">
<label>Question? </label>
Nein
</div>


<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("form-item webform-component webform-component-display webform-component--1-contact-1-bg20-custom-4")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
```

You were missing index to be specified after `getElementsByClassName` and additional `'`

Comment: You forgot that getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object, so it should be document.getElementsByClassName("form-item")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";

Comment: @Mr.Greenwoodz yeah I was updating it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` will return you an array of elements. So if you are sure that you just have one element with that combination of classes then you can try

```
 document.getElementsByClassName
 ("form-item webform-component webform-component-display 
   webform-component--1-contact-1-bg20-custom-4")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: The trouble is that OP believes `"form-item webform-component webform-component-display 
   webform-component--1-contact-1-bg20-custom-4"` is _one_ class name with spaces.

Comment: @Jeremy Thille, your comment on the question should get him to check back on the difference, hopefully. 

Thanks for that @RogerC!